# Most common value in a where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

There are plenty of answers out there for finding the most common value in a column, but what I want to do is identify a group in Column 1, by most common value in Column 2, not just find the common value itself:

```
EmployeeID | SicknessReason
---------------------------
1          | Cough
1          | Cough
1          | Cold
2          | Flu
2          | Flu
2          | Cough
3          | Cough
3          | Cough
3          | Cough
```

I want to find all EmployeeIDs whose most common SicknessReason is 'Cough', for example, so in this example, I want to return EmployeeIDs 1 and 3.

EDIT: In the real world, there are more columns which require the same approach, i.e. most common SicknessReason = 'Cough' AND most common ReportingMethod = 'SMS' and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a slight variation of calculating the most common reason (statistically the "mode"):

```
select employeeId
from (select employeeId, sicknessreason, count(*) as cnt
             dense_rank() over (partition by employeeId order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from t
      group by employeeId, sicknessreason
     ) es
where seqnum = 1 and sicknessreason = 'Cough';
```

Note that filtering on the reason occurs in the outer query, so it doesn't affect the `dense_rank()`.

Comment: thanks - in my real world table I have a lot more columns that need the same treatment i.e. I want to find unique EmployeeIDs whose most common SicknessReason is 'cough' AND whose most common ReportingMethod is 'sms' and.. and... What is the best way to apply this technique to multiple columns?

Comment: add such requirements to the question, they get hidden/buried in comments such as that one

Comment: @gh0st . . . Ask *another* question.  This question is pretty clear and refers to one column.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40627755/filtering-results-based-on-most-common-occurrences-of-values-in-other-columns-e

Answer (score 0):

Your example is missing something that makes each row unique. I took your example and loaded it into a table with an auto-number column (not shown) to make each entry unique.

```
    SELECT EmployeeID, Reason, Occurence = Count(*)
    FROM Test
    GROUP BY Reason, EmployeeID
    ORDER BY Count(*) DESC
```

Result:

```
    EmployeeID  Reason  Occurrence 
    3           Cough       3
    1           Cough       2
    2           Flu         2
    1           Cold        1
    2           Cough       1
```