# Filtering results based on most common occurrences of values in other columns (excluding outlying values)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Consider the following table and pseudo query:

```
Distinct Customers
WHERE
Most common PaymentMethod = 'CreditCard'
AND
Most common DeliveryService = '24hr'

Customer    TransID   PaymentMethod   DeliveryService
-----------------------------------------------------
Susan       1         CreditCard        24hr
Susan       2         CreditCard        24hr
Susan       3         Cash              24hr
John        4         CreditCard        48hr
John        5         CreditCard        48hr
Diane       6         CreditCard        24hr
Steve       7         Paypal            24hr
Steve       8         CreditCard        48hr
Steve       9         Paypal            24hr


Should return (2) records:

Customer
---------
Susan
Diane
```

Another way to look at it is that I want to exclude minority cases, i.e.:
**I don't want to return 'Steve', because although he used a creditcard once, he doesn't generally do so**, I only care about the majority behaviour, across multiple columns.

In reality, there are more columns (10s) that need the same principle applied so I'm after a technique that will scale at least that far searching 100ks of records.

Comment: First you say "Should return one record: Susan", but then you say "I don't want to return 'Susan'". Do you want Susan or not?

Comment: please post expected output

Comment: @jarlh Susan should be returned for the parameters in the pseudo-query above the table, i.e. paymentmethod=creditcard and deliveryservice=24hr. Were the paymentmethod to be cash, I do not want to return Susan, despite her having a record which includes cash, because it is not her most common payment method.

Comment: @chanukya ok, modified example

Comment: So find all customers, order by percentage of time credit card was used, descending?

Comment: what is the criteria to determine 'most common' ? `> 1`?

Comment: @mcNets >=50% of occurrences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses window functions and aggregation:

```
with cp as (
     select customerid, paymentmethod, count(*) as cnt,
            rank() over (partition by customerid order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
     from t
     group by customerid, paymentmethod
    ),
    cd as (
     select customerid, deliveryservice, count(*) as cnt
            rank() over (partition by customerid over by count(*) desc) as seqnum
     from t
     group by customerid, deliveryservice
    )
select cp.customerid
from cp join
     cd
     on cp.customerid = cd.customerid
where (cp.seqnum = 1 and cp.PaymentMethod = 'CreditCard') and
      (cd.seqnum = 1 and cd.DeliveryService = '24hr');
```

Because you need the ranks along two different dimensions, I think you need two subqueries (or the equivalent).

Comment: that's it - by using a single CTE which selects and groups by customer, deliveryservice, paymentmethod, I get the effect I'm looking for. It's useful to have this example for calculating the mode on each column independently.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE #D
(
Customer   VARCHAR(50), TransID INT,  PaymentMethod  VARCHAR(50),  DeliveryService VARCHAR(50)
)
INSERT INTO #D VALUES
('Susan',1,'CreditCard','24hr'),
('Susan',2,'CreditCard','24hr'),
('Susan',3,'Cash','24hr'),
('John ',4,'CreditCard','48hr'),
('John ',5,'CreditCard','48hr'),
('Diane',6,'CreditCard','24hr'),
('Steve',7,'Paypal','24hr'),
('Steve',8,'CreditCard','48hr'),
('Steve',9,'Paypal','24hr')


;with cte as
(
SELECT *,row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY PaymentMethod,Customer ORDER BY TransID) AS RN FROM #D
)
select DISTINCT Customer FROM cte  where    PaymentMethod = 'CreditCard'
AND DeliveryService = '24hr' and rn>1
```

Comment: My mistake; I didn't spot in the example that 'Diane' should also have been returned - this code only returns one record, whereas I want to return __all__ records that match the criteria.

Comment: Diane
Susan these two should come ..@gh0st

Comment: @gh0st accept my answer . comparitively i posted first with simple query

Comment: consider the following data, John appears in the resultset, which he should not:

    ('Susan',1,'CreditCard','24hr'),
    ('Susan',2,'CreditCard','24hr'),
    ('Susan',3,'Cash','24hr'),
    ('John',4,'Paypal','48hr'),
    ('John',5,'Paypal','48hr'),
    ('John',6,'CreditCard','24hr'),
    ('Diane',7,'CreditCard','24hr'),
    ('Diane',8,'CreditCard','24hr'),
    ('Steve',9,'CreditCard','24hr'),
    ('Steve',10,'CreditCard','48hr')

Comment: even his query returning the same i checked now only..@gh0st

Comment: expected output should  be  ...@gh0st

Comment: with data:  
`('Susan',1,'CreditCard','24hr'),
('Susan',2,'CreditCard','24hr'), 
('Susan',3,'Cash','24hr'), 
('John',4,'Paypal','48hr'), 
('John',5,'Paypal','48hr'), 
('John',6,'CreditCard','24hr'), 
('Diane',7,'CreditCard','24hr'), 
('Diane',8,'CreditCard','24hr'), 
('Steve',9,'CreditCard','24hr'), 
('Steve',10,'CreditCard','48hr'),
('Steve',11,'Paypal','24hr')`

Expected output should be

`Susan
Diane`  

Steve is a marginal case, but it would be better to not be included. @Chanukya

Comment: can u check my answer..@gh0st

Comment: With this code, simply having 2 matching records will put the customer in the resultset, even if they had more records that did not match. The following data shows this - Susan should __not__ be in the results because creditcard and 24hrs are not her most common values:
<br/>
`('Susan',1,'CreditCard','24hr'),
('Susan',2,'Cash','48hr'),
('Susan',3,'CreditCard','24hr'),
('Susan',4,'Cash','48hr'), 
('Susan',5,'Cash','48hr'), 
('Susan',6,'Cash','48hr'),
('Susan',7,'Cash','48hr')`

Answer (score 1):

Try this out..

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP (Customer varchar(20),TransID INT, PaymentMethod varchar(20),DeliveryService VARCHAR(10))
    INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES
    ('Susan',1,'CreditCard','24hr'),
    ('Susan',2,'CreditCard','24hr'),
    ('Susan',3,'Cash','24hr'),
    ('John',4,'CreditCard','48hr'),
    ('John',5,'CreditCard','48hr'),
    ('Diane',6,'CreditCard','24hr'),
    ('Steve',7,'Paypal','24hr'),
    ('Steve',8,'CreditCard','48hr'),
    ('Steve',9,'Paypal','24hr');



SELECT DISTINCT Customer FROM (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY PaymentMethod,Customer ORDER BY Customer) AS RNPaymentMethod,
ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY DeliveryService,Customer ORDER BY Customer) AS RNDeliveryService,Customer,TransID,PaymentMethod,DeliveryService FROM #TEMP) X
WHERE  X.PaymentMethod = 'CreditCard' AND X.DeliveryService = '24hr' AND X.RNPaymentMethod=1 AND X.RNDeliveryService=1
```

PS: I kept additional ROW NUMBER for **Delivery service** as well ,since you mentioned we need to look into the majority behaviour across **multiple columns**.

Hope this helps!

Comment: very helpful, for a bonus round, if we change the PaymentMethod of TranID=7 to 'CreditCard', Steve pops up in the results (and rightly so). Is there a way to exclude him on the basis that we want to consider the multi-column criteria __together__, i.e. he hasn't used CreditCard **and** 24hr together in the majority of transactions?

Comment: @PK spoke too soon, with the following data inserted, John appears in the resultset, which he shouldn't:

('Susan',1,'CreditCard','24hr'),
('Susan',2,'CreditCard','24hr'), 
('Susan',3,'Cash','24hr'), 
('John',4,'Paypal','48hr'), 
('John',5,'Paypal','48hr'), 
('John',6,'CreditCard','24hr'), 
('Diane',7,'CreditCard','24hr'), 
('Diane',8,'CreditCard','24hr'), 
('Steve',9,'CreditCard','24hr'), 
('Steve',10,'CreditCard','48hr')

Comment: @gh0st I understood your scenario but I am not able to analyze data properly. As per your latest data what should be the result in case of **Steve**..should he be part of output result or not, since he satisfy **PaymentMethod** case but what about **DeliveryService**.There is one with 24hrs and other with 48hrs(50%-50%).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let me try.

According to the question, you need to know the **most common occurrence**, and I think you must declare a function that returns exactly this:

For this example I used the same values of the temporary table, but I created a permanent table, if not, I can't create and test the functions. I truly believe this functions can be optimized, but I have no time for more.

Using functions you can modify  formula, and adequate it to your criteria.

```
create function most_common_payment(@customer varchar(100))
returns varchar(100)
as
begin
    declare @total int, @payment varchar(100), @max_times int

    -- total records
    select @total = COUNT(*) from tempD where Customer=@customer;
    if @total = 0 return ''

    -- max ocurrences payment method
    select top 1 @payment = PaymentMethod, @max_times = count(*)
    from tempd 
    where Customer = @customer
    group by Customer, PaymentMethod
    order by COUNT(*) desc;
    if  @max_times <= 1 return '';

    -- percentatge
    if ((@max_times * 100) / @total) < 50 set @payment = '';

    return @payment;
end
go
```

and the same for DeliveryService

```
crate function most_common_delivery(@customer varchar(100))
returns varchar(100)
as
begin

    declare @total int, @delivery varchar(100), @max_times int

    -- total records
    select @total = COUNT(*) from tempD where Customer=@customer;
    if @total = 0 return ''

    -- max ocurrences payment method
    select top 1 @delivery = DeliveryService, @max_times = count(*)
    from tempd 
    where Customer = @customer
    group by Customer, DeliveryService
    order by COUNT(*) desc;
    if  @max_times <= 1 return '';

    -- percentatge
    if ((@max_times * 100) / @total) < 50 set @delivery = '';

    return @delivery;
end
```

Ok, now I can query the desired result:

```
select distinct
    Customer
    ,dbo.most_common_payment(tempd.Customer) as MostCommonPayment
    ,dbo.most_common_delivery(tempd.Customer) as MostCommonDelivery
from
    tempd
where
    dbo.most_common_payment(tempd.Customer) = 'CreditCard'
    and dbo.most_common_delivery(tempd.Customer) = '24hr'
```

And this is the result:

```
Customer   MostCommonPayment    MostCommonDelivery
--------   -----------------    ------------------
Susan      CreditCard           24hr
```

Without filter

```
Customer   MostCommonPayment    MostCommonDelivery
--------   -----------------    ------------------
Diane
John       CreditCard           48hr
Steve      Paypal               24hr
Susan      CreditCard           24hr
```

Comment: very close - this treats the different columns we are looking at independently when finding the most common occurrences, how could it work where we want treat them as combined, i.e. only rows in which both Payment=CreditCard __and__ Delivery=24hrs are counted? @mcNets

Comment: isn't this: `where
    dbo.most_common_payment(tempd.Customer) = 'CreditCard'
    and dbo.most_common_delivery(tempd.Customer) = '24hr'` ?

Comment: because the 'most common' value for each column is determined independently, it will return a customer who has mostly used creditcard and mostly used 24hr, but actually never used both on the same transaction, I'm after a way to only count times when both are used on the same row towards the 'most common'. @mcNets

Comment: @gh0st, Ah ok, of course this function can and must be improved, and I'm sure that some SQL guru can get it, with fewer code than me. I'll try later, I think it's possible with a dynamic query.